# Understanding the gcc library search path

Tags: linux, command-line, fedora

I look at `ld.so.conf`, it reads:

```
include ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
```

OK, so I go to the include and see these files:

```
bind99-x86_64.conf                  kernel-4.16.11-100.fc26.x86_64.conf
kernel-4.11.8-300.fc26.x86_64.conf  libiscsi-x86_64.conf
```

Now two of those files are place holders, the other two list about five libs between them.

Yet `ldconfig -v` will list several pages of libs.  Obviously there are default lib path assignments inside my fedora that specify these search paths not in `ld.co.conf`. For example, `/usr/lib64` must be set somewhere, I cannot trace it via `ld.so.conf`.

I could not identify any lib path environmental variable that sets the internal default lib path.

Comment: the `/etc/ld.so.conf*` files only contain *directories* that will be searched for libraries by ldconfig(8) when building the `ld.so.cache` file. They're not used by either gcc, ld or the dynamic linker [ld.so(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) -- but the latter *will* use the `ld.so.cache` created by ldconfig.

Answer (score 1):

`ldconfig` looks at a few [“trusted directories”](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ldconfig.8.html) by default, in addition to those explicitly listed in its configuration files. On Fedora on 64-bit x86, these are `/lib`, `/lib64`, and [directories corresponding to hardware capabilities](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html#NOTES) (typically, `/lib/i686`, `/lib/sse2`, `/lib64/tls`, and `/lib/sse2`).

Note that `ldconfig` only affects runtime behaviour; it doesn’t affect GCC.